# Classic VM Resource Health == "Unavailable" twice in last 2 days

Tags: azure, virtual-machine

Our Classic VM in Azure has been off line a lot lately.
Resource Health shows an "Unavailable" status but claims no user interaction needed but to wait.
This has happened 2 times in the last 2 days. Waiting does not help. Restarting the VM does but that is taking longer and longer now. We  know we have to migrate by March 2023 but now is not a good time.

Answer (score 0):

•   ***`The classic VM resource health showing the state as unavailable means that the virtual machine is unavailable, and Azure is working to automatically recover your virtual machine and to determine the source of the problem. No additional action is required from you at this time. The health of this virtual machine may be impacted by an Azure service outage. Your virtual machine will automatically recover when the outage is resolved. It might also mean that we are currently unable to determine the reason for this downtime.`***

For more information regarding the resource health as ‘unavailable’, kindly refer the details given in the link below: -

***https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-services/resource-health-for-cloud-services#what-does-it-mean-by-role-instance-being-unavailable***

•   Also, do ensure that you **migrate your classic Azure VM managed through Azure Service Manager to the normal usual Azure VMs managed through Azure Resource Manager which is a replacement of the basic Azure Fabric software used for deploying Azure resources**. Since, *`the management of these classic VMs is already deprecated and more than 90% of the VMs are normal ARM VMs, therefore, after 28th February 2020, you cannot deploy classic VMs, thus since this VM is created prior to that, it is facing maintenance issues since it must be taken down for managed OS updates, resource management through virtualization layer, etc. and others`*.

Thus, there is not much that you can do other than migrating these classic VMs to newer normal VMs managed by ARM. For more detailed information, kindly refer to the below link regarding this: -

***https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/classic-vm-deprecation***